Digraph Walk Counting with Constraints on Reuse of Node and Edges
I am in the progress of a responsible disclosure for a reflected denial of service problem. The vulnerability is already confirmed and I am working on a estimate of worst-case impact. I have taken a couple classes in graph theory and 1 in combinatorics (and am currently doing a masters in statistics) but never seen a problem like this..
The mathematics of the problem can be simplified to:
Given a fully connected digraph of $N$ nodes.
Define $W$ as all walks in this digraph not exceeding length $k$ where no edge is used more than $m$ times. Self loops do not count toward the $k$ limit but the total walk length still cannot exceed 64. (A solution not considering this self-loop exception is still very helpful!)
Find a optimal multiset of $W$, let's call it $S$, subject to each node is not used as the start of the walk more than $pm$ times. Define $\text{load}(S)$ as the sum of the length of all walks in $S$.
The impact of this attack is characterized as $L' = \text{load}(S) / (N * m)$. Which obviously is the objective of this optimization.
As an attacker perspective, you can choose $m$ as long as the computation is not prohibitive to you, but N is an external factor at least 10 (I cannot give an upper bound due to confidentiality issues), and $p$ is an external factor between $[1, 10]$, $k$ is an external factor between $[4, 32]$.
The question is: What is the big O of $L'$ with respect to $N$? (If a generalized answer is hard, answer to a specific set of parameters is very useful too) The practicality is if this is higher than $1$ it means the attacker have a theoretical advantage for every additional node.
My current thoughts are:
It is unlikely an attacker can compute the optimal $S$ in a reasonable amount of time for even $N = 10$, however can you model the big O of $L'$ mathematically without necessarily defining how to practically find the optimal $S$?
If even $L'$ is hard to model, what about modeling specific cases where $S$ is chosen heuristically:
A solution for $N/2$ can easily be transformed into one for $N$ by "mirroring" the solution for new $N/2$ nodes. This clearly is $O(1)$ to the original question.
A heuristics approach that does better (although I am not sure how to estimate by how much) I can think of is:

Compute the solution for a small $N_s$ and a slightly lower $m$ (for transition later).
Partition the nodes into groups of $N_s$, execute the above solution.
"Transpose" this group by assigning each node to a different group where all in-group edges become out-group.
Execute (2) again with the new partition until all avenues are exhausted.

